# Build Jacksons ObjectMapper in particular case when global settings are configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

In my application I configured Jackson to use `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` and `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` globally.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.featuresToEnable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

This configuration works fine but now I am in a situation where in `deserialization` case I get a JSON Response without `rootname`. So I have got a Service Class which builds a `RestTemplate` using `RestTemplateBuilder` and `POST` some Data to a REST-Webservice.

```
@Service
public class ApiServiceImpl
        implements ApiService<RegisterResponse> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ApiServiceImpl(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .errorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler()).build();
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<RegisterResponse> callAPI(String requestAsJson,
            String username, String password) {
        ResponseEntity<RegisterResponse> result = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders(username, password);

        result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<String>(requestAsJson, headers),
                RegisterResponse.class);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The Response looks like the following:

```
{
    "redirect-url": "https://any-url.com/?with=params"
}
```

And I want to deserialize this to the following POJO directly. (Like in restTemplate.exchange configured)

```
public class RegisterResponse {

    @JsonProperty("redirect-url")
    private String redirectUrl;
    //getter/setter
}
```

It's clear to get this exception because of the `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` Feature:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Root name 'redirect-url' does not match expected ('RegisterResponse') for type [simple type, class xxx.xxx.xxxservice.xxx.model.response.entity.RegisterResponse]
 at [Source: (String)"{
    "redirect-url": "https://any-url.com/?with=params"
}"; line: 2, column: 5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1356)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._unwrapAndDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:4087)
```

**How can I configure `Jackson` to dont use `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` in this particular case?**

Comment: Get the message converter of type MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter i the list of converters of the RestTemplate, and set its ObjectMapper to a different instance of ObjectMapper which has the UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE feature disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Like JB Nizet commented, its possibly by setting a new Instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `ObjectMapper` for Jakson to the list of `MessageConverters`.

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(getCustomConverter());

private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter getCustomConverter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customConverter = 
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
        if (!restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
                .removeIf(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)) {
            new RuntimeException("Custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter not found");
        }
        return customConverter;
    }
```